# How should I retrieve original pictures included with the Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My application uses the Facebook Javascript SDK to add wall posts to the feed of a community's page, and to retrieve them again. Pictures included with the posts are processed and placed somewhere on the Facebook servers.

When these posts are retrieved the links to the pictures turn out to be links pointing to the fbcdn.net server.

Is there a way to access the original links?

Update:

Here is my code posting a post:

```
    // The "params" variable contains a field called "picture"
    // (which is a link pointing to my picture)
    FB.addWallPost = function (params, pageId, token, complete) {
        var fbApiParams = {
            access_token: token
        };
        $.extend(fbApiParams, params);
        FB.api(pageId + '/feed', 'post', fbApiParams, function (response) {
            // FB.apiCallDone is a function checking if there's any positive response
            if (FB.apiCallDone(response)) {
                complete(response.id);
            }
            else {
                complete(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

And these lines retrieve the posts:

```
FB.getWallPosts = function (wallPostsIds, token, complete) {
    if (wallPostsIds && wallPostsIds != null && wallPostsIds.length) {
        var wallPostsIdsStr = wallPostsIds.join(',');
        var fbApiParams = {
            ids: wallPostsIdsStr,
            access_token: token
        };
        FB.api('/', fbApiParams, function (response) {
            if (FB.apiCallDone(response)) {
                var wallPosts = dictElemsToArr(response);                    
                complete(wallPosts);
            }
            else {
                complete([]);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        complete([]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually posting the pictures, or is Facebook getting the pictures from your meta tags from the Open Graph?

Comment: See updated post, @Coulton. I actually post pictures.

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting pictures to Facebook, they will be stored locally by Facebook.

It is up to your application to store the path of the original images if your application requires this information.